# how to make accordion in ios with image

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I would like to ask on how to hide the image in accordion using UITableView? First I create tableview and delegate it. here is the code of my viewcontroller

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "ListViewCell.h"
@interface ViewController (){
    NSArray * tableData;
    NSInteger currentSelection;
    int one;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    one = 0;
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    tableData = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Egg Benedict", @"Mushroom Risotto", @"Full Breakfast", @"Hamburger", @"Ham and Egg Sandwich", @"Creme Brelee", @"White Chocolate Donut", @"Starbucks Coffee", @"Vegetable Curry", @"Instant Noodle with Egg", @"Noodle with BBQ Pork", @"Japanese Noodle with Pork", @"Green Tea", @"Thai Shrimp Cake", @"Angry Birds Cake", @"Ham and Cheese Panini", nil];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    return [tableData count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"mycell";

    ListViewCell *cell = (ListViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        [tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"listxib" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"mycell"];
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    }
     cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    return cell;

}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    if ([indexPath row] == currentSelection && one !=0) {
        return  312;
    }
    else return 75;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    currentSelection = [indexPath row];

    if(one==1){
        NSLog(@"%@",@"active");
        one = 0; // check if this is active


    }else{
       NSLog(@"%@",@"not active");
        one =1;
    }


    [tableView beginUpdates];
    [tableView endUpdates];
}
```

I have no problems displaying text on the label in the cell. I create xib file to inherit it to my tableview cell and the name of the UITableviewCell controller is ListViewCell. see my image bellow

[image]

when I used that xib and display to my UITableview i get this result
[image]

I you see the image. The big image of that girl overlap the UITableView. It supposed to be hide, it will only diplay when user click the cell and expand the height of cell. I try to find it in google but they don't have tutorial that using xib file. I enable the AUTOLAYOUT in my setting. Does autolayout matters when doing an accordion with xib? I always think thank this autolayout makes me sick when doing project like this. hoping you understand what I want to do. But if you have tutorial out there. That will be super duper nice to see it.

Comment: http://www.codedisqus.com/0yzVPUWeWj/accordion-table-cell-for-expand-and-collapse-ios.html go through this may be it will help you

Comment: I will read that tutorial. tnx @Sushrita

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try select the large image view in your cell xib file, select properties and tick clip to subviews.

Comment: that answer you post is it working in any lower version of iphone just like iphone 4s?

Comment: @user3818576 for your reference
Availability
Available in iOS 2.0 and later, is it working for you?

Comment: ok2x thanks for your answer. I get it now. almost a week now trying to solve this in my own.